# Transform a rectangle to a specific shape using java

Tags: java, java-2d, matrix-transform

Is there a way to transform a rectangle to a shape that is shown in the image..?
[image: Transformation]

I have tried every way I can using AffineTransform to do this. But I couldn't  get the the expected result. I want to make sure is this a impossible task or is there a way to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) by definition preserves points, straight lines and planes.

So you can at best transform your rectangle to a rotated parallelogram at best (Opposite lines will remain parallel).

To achieve more complex shapes, you need more general transformation like [**Projective transformation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography) (also known as Homography) (affine transformation is a special kind of projective transformation).